# Code generate C# class from existing class

Tags: c#, t4, codedom

I'd like to find a way of generating a C# class from an existing class. For some of my application service classes I like to create a servicebuildertest class to help with unit testing and want to generate this on the fly....

example:
I have a class

```
public class MyAppService
{
   public MyAppService(IRepository<Person> personRepository, etc....)
   {
   }
}
```

and I want to create the test builder class

```
public class MyAppServiceTestBuilder
{
    private IRepository<Person> _personRepository;

    public void WithPersonRepository(Mock<IRepository<Person>> personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository.Object;
    }

    public void Build()
    {
        return new MyAppService(
         _personRepository ?? new Mock<IRepository<Person>>().Object);
    }
}
```

Could do with some tips for which technology to use:
I've had the following suggestions: CodeDOM, Roslyn, T4.

With T4 it appears that you need a template for each file, which I don't really want, I guess the benefit would be any change to the applicationservice would automatically update the testbuilder.

I started down the route of CodeDOM, but someone suggested that it is an old technology and that Roslyn does the same and a whole lot more...

Many thanks....

Comment: What stage are you at with this? Are you already generating the code, but looking for a way to generate it on the fly, or haven't you got that far yet?

Comment: Sorry I meant "compile it on the fly" in my question.

Comment: I have written the code in CodeDOM (with the exception of null coalesce operator, which is not supported), but I have this in a separate console application which references the library which contains my app service.

Comment: So, in essence it's currently a bit clunky. I'd like to find a way I could have it running within the working solution.

Comment: When you say "Generate on the fly" do you mean create a new cs file in your test project based on a selected class in another project?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Sorry, maybe not very clear from my explanation!